# How to deal with empty dict value

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

I have a json list in the form of a dictionary, and the following allows me to get values out of the dict:

```
valone = out['red']['blue']['green']

valtwo = out['purple']['yellow']['black']
```

From there I can run a conditional statement around valone or valtwo to see if they they are black of green.

Now this works very well, when those keys are populated, but when they are not I get

```
KeyError: 'black'
```

This is I can see as the value is empty.

I am having a hard time working out how to filter out before the declaration  of the dict values.

I have seen people suggest

```
out.get("black", None)
```

But I cannot access black, as I its the third value I am after?

Comment: What is the complete value of `out` (i.e. output of `print(repr(out))`).?

Comment: `out['purple']['yellow'].get('black', None)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are using multi-level indexing, the cleanest way is to use exception to control the flow (which is quite accepted in Python though often frowned upon in other languages)

```
try:
    valone = out['red']['blue']['green']
except KeyError:
    # Handle Your Exception Here
```

Comment: except KeyError:           Perfect - many thanks!         Will accpet answer when time period reaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the try/except syntax:

```
try:
    valone = out['red']['blue']['green']
except:
    # whatever
```

Comment: A catch-all statement isn't the best practice.  Here, you know you'll run into a `KeyError` at least, so that should be caught.